# Middle Click Drag does not rotate the view

Tags: 3d-view

Blender 2.8 and the RC2 also, but not immediately after install.
Windows 10.
The middle mouse click and drag works OK for other things.
I think I tried everything.

Comment: The informative display at the bottom shows the middle mouse button but not "Rotate View" next to it.  In what python could I have a look ?  Of course I already reinstalled Blender.

Comment: I also reloaded factory settings, repaired Blender and so on.  Now I "solved" the problem by downloading some branch from Graphicall.